# Validator Does Not Show Errors At Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a Controller method like this:

```php
use Validator;
public function insert(Request $request)
{
    $data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
        'title' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required|alpha_num',
        'activation' => 'nullable',
        'cachable' => 'nullable'
    ])->validated();

    $wallet = new Wallet();
    $wallet->title = $data['title'];
    $wallet->name = $data['name'];

    if (!empty($data['activation'])) {
        $wallet->is_active = 1;
    } else {
        $wallet->is_active = 0;
    }

    if (!empty($data['cachable'])) {
        $wallet->is_cachable = 1;
    } else {
        $wallet->is_cachable = 0;
    }

    $wallet->save();
    
    return redirect(url('admin/wallets/index'));
}
```

And then I tried showing errors like this:

```
@error("name")
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{$message}}</div>
@enderror
```

But the problem is, it does not print any error when I fill the form incorrectly.

So how to fix this and show errors properly?

Here is the form itself, however it submits data to the DB correctly:

```
<form action="{{ route('insertWallet') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="title-shop" name="title" class="form-control" value="" autofocus>
    
    @error("title")
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{$message}}</div>
    @enderror
    
    <label for="title" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="title-shop" name="name" class="form-control" value="" autofocus>
    
    @error("name")
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{$message}}</div>
    @enderror
    
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="cachable" value="cashable" id="cacheStatus">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="cacheStatus">
    &nbsp; With Cash
    </label>
    
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="activaton" value="active" id="activationStatus">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="activationStatus">
    &nbsp; Be Active
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: try importing facade use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator; and show full blade code

Comment: @JohnLobo I tried it but didn't solve the problem, I also added the whole form

Comment: your form  validation shows as expected. i have tested  it with all empty fields .try clearing cache php artisan view:clear and php artisan clear and make sure import facade use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

Answer (score 0):

check the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators)

add the following code

```
if($data->fails()){
     return redirect(url('admin/wallets/index'))->withErrors($data)->withInput();
}
```

And after that save your data in your database

Comment: Good answer, but that is not the best way, [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) as it shows a cleaner way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any errors, you are just redirecting back to the view without any data.

Your fix would be to have your validator as this:

```
$data = Validator::validate(request()->all(),[
    'title' => 'required',
    'name' => 'required|alpha_num',
    'activation' => 'nullable',
    'cachable' => 'nullable'
]);
```

See that I have changed `Validator::make` to `Validator::validate`. As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) states:

> If the validation rules pass, your code will keep executing normally; however, if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the proper error response will automatically be sent back to the user.

> If validation fails during a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response to the previous URL will be generated. If the incoming request is an XHR request, a JSON response containing the validation error messages will be returned.

So, if your validation passes, it will save all the validated data into `$data`, as you did with `->validated()` (but you don't have to write it here), and if it fails, it will automatically throw an Exception, in this case `ValidationException`, so Laravel will automatically handle it and **redirect** back with to the same URL and with the `errors`. So it now should work...

[This is the `Validator::validate` source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b75203ef337c22bec4918c26dbfc529f8dbf13ba/src/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.php#L143-L146) and [this is the `validate` source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b75203ef337c22bec4918c26dbfc529f8dbf13ba/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L473-L480) for the `validator validate` method.